# phpMyAdmin This page isn’t working right now on ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 8.1

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

After a couple of days and countless hours.. I have failed. I'm trying to setup a fresh Linux server running Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2, Mysql, and PHP 8.1. I ran into an issue right after the phpMyAdmin installation which went well. When trying access the phpMyAdmin interface located at domain.com/phpmyadmin - I get the following error:

This page isn’t working right now domain.com can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I have done a lot of research, reinstalled the server about 5 times but I still can't figure out what the problem is. I hope you guys and help me out! I appreciate your time in advance.!

Comment: The HTTP 500 error is most likely pointing to a PHP issue. You will want to look at the error logs in `/var/log/apache2` in order to trace the issue down.

Comment: @matigo I checked my error logs and sure enough. There was a php error in there. I'm trying to update my post with the error log record.

Comment: Most probably related to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17585